# How to install expect and tcl on linux RHEL server 6.5

Tags: tcl, redhat, expect

I am new to linux and i have few expect scripts to execute. I read few blogs on how to install expect and tcl. The command i am trying is

```
sudo yum install expect
sudo yum install tcl
```

I am getting

```
No package expect available
No package tcl available
```

It seems RHEL should have tcl and expect prebuilt but this is not the case in my version of linux.

How should i proceed from here ?
Help will be highly appreciated..Thanks :)

Comment: Have you checked what `yum list 'tcl*'` says?

Answer (score 1):

Install the development tools: 
 yum groupinstall "Development tools"

then

./configure
make
make install

should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? In this way you will be able to compile from source.

1)    Download the expect package from the below link

```
                    http://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/
```

2)    Install the required dependecy packages "Tcl/Tk" language toolkit

```
                    # yum install tcl
```

3)    Install the "expect" package using the below commands

```
        # tar -zxvf expectx.xx.tar.gz
        # ./configure
        # make
        # make install
```

Comment: Yes, it says No package tcl available

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following links and it worked for me. http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/tcl.html http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/expect.html

Answer (score 0):

Try ActiveTcl from ActiveState:

> The trusted Tcl distribution for Windows, Linux and Mac, pre-bundled
> with top Tcl/Tk modules.
>
> ActiveTcl includes a version of Tcl and popular packages, pre-compiled
> and ready to use

https://www.activestate.com/products/tcl/

Answer (score 0):

You can add EPEL Repo

```
On 32-Bit -
# rpm -Uvh http://epel.mirror.net.in/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

On 64-Bit -
# rpm -Uvh http://epel.mirror.net.in/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

and then you can use yum to install.
Also you can compile from source or get from ActiveState like in previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

From [Installing Tcl/Tk](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/installing_and_using_dynamic_programming_languages/assembly_installing-tcl-tk_installing-and-using-dynamic-programming-languages)

> Tcl is a dynamic programming language, while Tk is a graphical user
> interface (GUI) toolkit. They provide a powerful and easy-to-use
> platform for developing cross-platform applications with graphical
> interfaces

On RHEL9 you can do:

```
dnf install -y tcl tk expect
```

You get those versions

```
rpm -qa | grep -i tcl
tcl-8.6.10-7.el9.x86_64

rpm -qa | grep -w tk
tk-8.6.10-9.el9.x86_64

rpm -qa | grep expect
expect-5.45.4-15.el9.x86_64
```